# How to access a physical address which is larger than 4G in Trusted firmware provided by Linaro in juno board

Tags: arm, trustzone

I am using Trusted Firmware Image(LSK and Android filesystem) provided by Linaro on Juno board r1. In my case, I just want to some trivial test in EL3, e.g., reading specific memory.
To make things easier, I didn't do anything until the system is completely booted. Then I load a kernel module which sends a SMC instruction and the SMC exception will be handled in BL3-1 by a custom handler. In the handler, I disabled MMU for EL3 and attempted to access a physical address directly. But I found that if the physical address is larger than 0xffffffff(4G), the content I got will be all 0. The physical address lower than 0xffffffff works perfectly. And If I mapped that physical address into a virtual address smaller than 0xffffffff(Linaro's EL3 only support virtual address lower than 0xffffffff), it also works.
So, why I can not get the correct content of a physical address larger than 0xffffffff after I disabled MMU in EL3?

Is there anyone know the details?
Thanks a lot for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

The stock Juno firmware sets up the TrustZone controller such that 16MB of DRAM from `0x0ff000000` to `0x0ffffffff` is reserved for the Secure world, and the rest is Non-Secure only. The specific TZC configuration is such that the Non-Secure regions just read as zero and ignore writes, rather than aborting, for Secure accesses.

Thus it's not that you can't access *physical addresses* above 4GB per se, it's just that the only thing that happens to be up there is DRAM, which is the thing the secure world has specifically denied itself access to the majority of.

The relevant part of the firmware source [can be found here](https://github.com/ARM-software/arm-trusted-firmware/blob/master/plat/arm/common/arm_security.c).

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works. And I have another question about the memory map. I don't think disable MMU is a perfect idea to access certain physical memory and so I tried to dynamically add some memory map region in to translation table. But unfortunately, I didn't get a correct way to do it. Do you know whether it is possible to add some memory map region to translation table dynamically when I am in EL3?